# Grunt task to compile LESS in the same folder

Tags: gruntjs, less, web-component

I have the following folder structure:

```
Widgets
- Widget One
  - CSS
    - WigdetOneStyle.less
  - WidgetOne.JS
- Widget Two
  - CSS
    - WigdetOneStyle.less
  -WidgetOne.JS
Gruntfile.js
```

Is there a way to have grunt-contrib-less compile each widgets LESS file into their respective CSS folders?